# How to set up hydra config to accept a custom enum?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

How do I set up a my hydra config to accept a custom enum? Specifically I followed the [Structured Config Schema tutorial](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/schema/).

I have a dataclass config:

```
@dataclass_validate
@dataclass
class CustomConfig:
    custom_enum: CustomEnum
```

With the custom enum:

```
class CustomEnum(str, Enum):
    ENUM1 = "enum1"
    ENUM2 = "enum2"
```

Error from running `python my_app.py`

```
Error merging 'data/config' with schema
Invalid value 'enum1', expected one of [ENUM1, ENUM2]
    full_key: custom_enum
    object_type=CustomConfig
```

Where `my_app.py` is just:

```
cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="base_config", node=Config)
cs.store(group="data", name="config", node=CustomConfig)

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="config")
def setup_config(cfg: Config) -> None:
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
```

And the config in `data/config.yaml` is just

```
custom_enum: enum1
```

Comment: A word of caution: OmegaConf and Hydra do not currently have any test coverage for classes that simultaneously subclass `str` and `Enum`, as is the case with your `CustomEnum` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the error message: `Invalid value 'enum1', expected one of [ENUM1, ENUM2]`.

This is to say, in your `data/config.yaml` file, you should be using `ENUM1` instead of `enum1`.